# Google Sheets trying to add text to a cell with conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets I'm trying to add text to a different cell with a conditional formatting formula acting upon two other cells.

For example, I have a couple of columns... 'C' and 'E'.  I'm comparing the values in C25 and E25, like so:  `=E25<C25`.  That works, I can change a cell to red using that formula.

But what if I want to put a formula in cell F26 to print some text???

I tried this in F26:   Format | Conditional formatting... | Apply to range: F26 | select Custom formula is... | and typed: `=IF(E25<C25, "do something", "")`

When E25 is less than C25, I don't see "do something" appear in E26.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 4):

**Unfortunately, conditional formatting is not able to imprint any kind of text/numeric values.**

The only way how to do so is pasting **`=IF(E25<C25, "do something", )`** in **F26**. If you want to avoid formula per row, you will need to use **`ARRAYFORMULA()`** variance.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm really confused then, this example shows printing text values if a checkbox is checked.  Scroll down to section 3.  https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-checkbox/

Comment: you probably mean section 2... checkbox is part of "data validation" (which can imprint text/numeric values) not "conditional formatting". conditional formatting is only able to check checkbox/cell against some ruleset and evaluate if the custom conditional formatting formula is TRUE or FALSE and act accordingly to this by changing colors/bold/italic etc.

Comment: No, I meant section 3.  It shows if a condition is met, displaying text.